# I want to load a keras model in 3ds max and make it work

Tags: keras, 3dsmax, maxscript

Check if Python is running in the conda virtual environment

When I change the virtual environment to the command prompt and run it in Max, I get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

please help if you know

```
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
```

I got the same error minus numpy here.

Previously, I have created a script that sequentially operates the code written in Python and MaxScript.

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
import astropy
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, AltAz
from astropy.time import Time
import astropy.units as u
import datetime
```

The above worked fine.